# I have changed jobs and want to change my e-mail address but cannot find a way to do it

Tags: support, email

I unfortunately used the e-mail address from a previous job as my login e-mail address here, and now I cannot find a way to change it.  I could, of course, just create a new account, but I would lose all my reputation points, badges, etc., and would like to avoid "starting over."  If anyone knows how I can change my e-mail address without wiping the slate clean, I would love to know how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to change how you login to the site? Just to be clear. If yes, go to your profile (on main, not on Meta) > "Edit Profile & Settings" > "My Logins" and add a new login. You can then remove the old one. (Not posting this as an answer as I am 1000% sure this is a duplicate.)